# Python 'list.insert()' only saves the last result of calculation loop

Tags: python, list

I was making my automatic stock strategy yield calculation program with Python. Here's my code:

```
import FinanceDataReader as fdr 
import numpy as np
# ...(more modules for python)

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format

file_list = os.listdir('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel')

for i in range(20): 

os.chdir('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel')
odd = file_list[i]

data = pd.read_excel('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel/'+str(odd))

def calMACD(data, short=5, long=25, signal=9):
    data.sort_index()
    
    data['MVA_25']=data['Close'].ewm(span=long, adjust=False).mean()
    data['MVA_5']=data['Close'].ewm(span=short, adjust=False).mean()
    data['MACD']=data['Close'].ewm(span=short, adjust=False).mean() - data['Close'].ewm(span=long, adjust=False).mean()
    data['Signal']=data['MACD'].ewm(span=signal, adjust=False).mean( )
    #data['Buy_sign']=(data['MACD']-data['Signal']) >=600
    data['Buy_sign']=np.where(data['MACD']-data['Signal'] >=451, 'Buy' , 'Sell' )
    #data['Target_1']=(data['Close']-data['Close'].shift(1))/data['Close'].shift(1)*100
    #data['Target_1']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Buy', (data['Change'])+1,1)
    #data['Target_2']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Sell', (data['Change'])+1,1)
    #data['Real_world']= 1000000*data['Target_1']
    #data['Real_world_2']= 1000000*data['Target_2'] 
    #data['Condition'] = np.where(data['Real_world']<1000000, data['Real_world']-data['Real_world'].shift(-2),1)
    ##data['Condition_2'] = np.where(data['Real_world']<1000000, data['Target_1'].shift(-2),1)
    #data['Moneyflow'] = 
    #plt.plot(data['Date'], data['Real_world'])
    #data[data.Buy_sign !='Sell']
    
    

    '''
    data['Target_1']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Buy', data['Change'],1)
    data['Target_2']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Sell', data ['Change'],1)
    data['Yield']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Sell', data['Target_1']/data['Target_2'],1 )
    '''

    '''
    data['Result']=data['Target_1'].cumprod()
    data['Result_2']=data['Target_2'].cumprod()
    data['??????'] = data['Result'] - data['Result_2']
    '''

    return data


Adjusted = calMACD(data)
Adjusted.drop(['Change'], axis=1, inplace = True)
Filtered = Adjusted[Adjusted.Buy_sign!='Sell'].copy()

#print(Filtered)
#Filtered = (Adjusted.Buy_sign =='Buy') #(Adjusted.Condition = 1.0)
#Master = Adjusted.loc[Adjusted,['Date','Buy_sign','Target_1','Real_world',]]
#print(Adjusted)


def backtester(Filtered):
    Filtered['Change'] = ((Filtered['Close'] - Filtered['Close'].shift(1)) / Filtered['Close'].shift(1))+1
    #data['Target_1']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Buy', (data['Change'])+1,1)
    Filtered['Real_world'] = 1000000*Filtered['Change']
    #Filtered['Condition'] = np.where(Filtered['Real_world']<1000000, Filtered['Real_world'].shift(-2)-Filtered['Real_world'],1)
    Filtered['Condition'] = np.where(Filtered['Real_world']<1000000, Filtered['Change'].shift(-2),1)
    #Filtered['Target_1'] = np.where(Filtered['Buy_sign']=='Buy', (Filtered['Change'])+1,1)
    #Filtered['Condition'] = np.where(Filtered['Real_world']<1000000, Filtered['Real_world'].shift(-2)-Filtered['Real_world'],1)

    return Filtered 
    
s = backtester(Filtered)

e = s[s.Condition!=1.00000]

x = e.dropna()

y = x['Condition']

list_1 = []

write_wb = Workbook()
write_ws = write_wb.create_sheet('MACD&Signal gap data sheet')
write_ws = write_wb.active
write_ws['A1'] = 'Name'
write_ws['B1'] = 'Profit'





try:
    print(geometric_mean(y)*1000000*12)

except StatisticsError as e:
    print ('Sell is empty':',odd)
else:
    d = (geometric_mean(y)*1000000*12)
    print(d,odd)
    list_1.insert(i,d)

 Print(list_1)
```

Here's the part where I'm troubling with:

```
s = backtester(Filtered)

e = s[s.Condition!=1.00000]

x = e.dropna()

y = x['Condition']

list_1 = []


try:
    print(geometric_mean(y)*1000000*12)

except StatisticsError as e:
    print ('Sell is empty':',odd)

else:
    d = (geometric_mean(y)*1000000*12)
    print(d)
    list_1.insert(d)

print(list_1)
```

When I initiate the code where I am having problems, list only saves the last result of 'try, except, else' function. My intention was saving all the results. What change should I give to save all the results?

Here's the output of the list:

```
 [11772769.197974786]
```

Comment: In your question, you are not careful with indentation, and in Python, indentation is what determines whether a statement in side one block or another. Is your for loop at the top actually outdented properly, or is it as shown here?

Comment: Next issue: between the statements `list_1 = []` and `list_1.insert(d)`, there is no loop. If all this is actually in a loop, then at each iteration you reset `list_1` to the empty list before the try/except/else block. I would guess this is your actual problem.

Comment: Thank you joanis! After I pull out list_1 to out of the loop, I could save all the results! There will be a luck on your path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use append, not insert. [see Python Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Change `list_1.insert(d)` to `list_1.append(d)`

The insert is defaulting to index 0 and just updating it each time.

Edit: Just noticed your answer is in the question title.

Comment: I tried list_1.append(d), but, it keep gives me the same result.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm kind of new to python but can't see the problem other than using .append.  Insert a print before the append and make sure there are multiple values passing through... I'm not sure why the else is used - that code could be in the try and then if there was an issue with (geometric_mean(y)*1000000*12) it would jump to except.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `insert` instead of `append` and the main difference that insert takes a second argument for the position that you want to insert your element at and when none is provided it is 0 by default so you are consistently inserting at the same index resulting in a list with only the last element at the first position.

To fix that simply use `append` instead.

```
else:
    d = (geometric_mean(y)*1000000*12)
    print(d)
    list_1.append(d)
```

Comment: I also tried append but i didn't work.

Comment: it can be a problem with indentation as well make sure all the blocks are indented at the same level as the block of the for loop in order to append all the iterations results